# Why am I not getting status code 200 and expected behavior when making requests to my app in unit tests?

Tags: flask, pytest, auth0

I'm creating unit tests for a Flask application that uses Auth0 for authentication with Pytest. Using the Auth0 API I've been able to find that a request for an authorization token can be made with the following code, which definitely works.

```
import http.client
import json
# Code taken from the API at https://manage.auth0.com/dashboard/us/api-name/apis/
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection(api-name.auth0.com")

payload = "{\"client_id\":\"MY_CLIENT_ID\",\"client_secret\":\"MY_CLIENT_SECRET\",\"audience\":\"MY_AUD\",\"grant_type\":\"client_credentials\"}"

headers = { 'content-type': "application/json" }

conn.request("POST", "/oauth/token", payload, headers)

res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()

# Decode the response data from bytes to a UTF-8 string
decoded_data = data.decode("utf-8")

# Parse the JSON data
response_json = json.loads(decoded_data)

# Extract the access token from the response
access_token = response_json.get('access_token')
headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}'}
```

Next, what I'd like to do is either login with auth0, which I have yet to figure out, or use the auth token above as a header in my requests to auth-required routes.

```
@pytest.fixture
def client():
    # Create a test client using the app
    app.testing = True
    with app.test_client() as client:
        client.environ_base['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] = headers['Authorization']
        yield client

def test_route(client):
    response = client.get("/route", headers=headers)
    assert b"<h2>Upload</h2>" in response.data
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

In the above code, I've attempted to grant authorization by setting the environ_base['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] key for my client to the authorization token I grab from the Auth0 API. I also use the headers in the headers optional argument for client.get() when it's called in test_route().

Finally I have attempted to use the Auth0 API to see if it was possible to query a page through Auth0. Here is that code:

```
import http.client

conn = http.client.HTTPConnection("path_to_your_api") 
# if audience URL is https://panda-home-fireplace.auth0.com/api/v2/,
# the path_to_your_api string would be panda-home-fireplace.auth0.com/api/v2/

headers = { 'authorization': "Bearer {access_token}" }

conn.request("GET", "/route", headers=headers)

res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()

print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

When attempting to run the Auth0 query code, I am met with this error: http.client.CannotSendRequest: Request-sent.
When attempting to use similar paths to API, I am met with socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed, leading me to believe that the laternative API paths are incorrect.

I am integrating testing into the workflow using GitHub actions. Whenever these tests run, I receive a 302 redirect and the following error message:

- where b'<!doctype html>\n\nRedirecting...\n

  ## Redirecting...

  \n

  You should be redirected automatically to the target URL: /. If not, click the link.\n' = <WrapperTestResponse 189 bytes [302 FOUND]>.data.

The expected behavior of the route I'm testing is for GET requests to render the HTML template and for POST requests to upload a file or set of files (what I'm attempting to unit test) and then render the same page, with a "Thank you for your upload!" splash message.

The code for the route in question is enumerated below:

```
@app.route('/route', methods=["GET", "POST"])
@requires_auth
def route():
    # generate timestamp
    time_submitted = get_current_time()

    userinfo=session[constants.PROFILE_KEY]
    user_id=userinfo['user_id']


    [...]

    success = None
    # check if request has the file part
    msg = ''

        if success:
            msg = 'Thank you for sending in ' + secure_filename(name) + '. Time submitted: ' + \
                time_submitted + '.'
        else:
            if msg == '':
                msg = 'Unable to submit ' + name + '. Allowed file extensions ' + \
                    'include: txt, pdf, png, jpg, jpeg, gif.'
    else:
        success = None
        name = None

    database.disconnect()

    html = render_template('./templates/route.html', unread=unread,
                        success=success, msg=msg, chapter_is_on=chapter_on)
    response = make_response(html)
    return response
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you happen to have `allow_redirects` set to `False` anywhere? It's one of the args for `requests.get()` that's set to True by default, but maybe something went wrong there...

Comment: I don't believe I have allow_redirects set to False anywhere.